# WPF Entity can't create an ObjectSet of a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have added a database view to my entity model. Now I am trying to put an `ObjectSet` into my `ObjectContext` so I can access the view in my application.

For regular tables my `ObjectSet` would look like this:

```
private ObjectSet<StarVendor> _StarVendor;
public ObjectSet<StarVendor> StarVendor
{
    get
    {
        if ((_StarVendor == null))
        {
            _StarVendor = base.CreateObjectSet<StarVendor>("Stratus_X_TestEntities.StarVendors");
        }
         return _StarVendor;
    }
}
```

So I did the same for my View:

```
private ObjectSet<CatalogItemSearch> _CatalogItemSearch;
public ObjectSet<CatalogItemSearch> CatalogItemSearch
{
    get
    {
        if ((_CatalogItemSearch == null))
        {
            _CatalogItemSearch = base.CreateObjectSet<CatalogItemSearch>("Stratus_X_TestEntities.CatalogItemSearch");
        }
        return _CatalogItemSearch;
    }
}
```

But when the code runs I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException "The EntitySet name
>   'Stratus_X_TestEntities.CatalogItemSearch' could not be found"

I know that for a View I don't need the add/update/delete functionality that `ObjectSet` provides.

Is there an alternative Set type that I should be using for this?

or could this error be from something totally unrelated to the fact that its a view?

thanks

Comment: As I understood it is Code First approach?

Comment: The view is pulled into the .edmx using 'Update Model from Database' function. I couldn't find a useful .tt file to generate my ObjectContext, so that portion is written by hand. So its not exactly "code first" as I understand it

Comment: By view I mean a database view; you know, instead of a regular table? As far as I know it should be working... I had been writing entity in Silverlight, I used to know how everything worked with RIA, but when I had to switch to WPF, so now Entity just doesn't work the same.... Hopefully Martin's suggestion to use a higher version will sort everything out

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that the `ObjectSet` API along with the `ObjectContext` API is the old API of the Entity Framework which usually is no longer used today.

It was part of Entity framework 4.0, that was a long time ago (see [Wikipedia: Entity Framework history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework#History)).

In 2011 Entity framework version 4.1 was released, and recommended using the `DbSet` and `DbContext` API instead from now on.
The current production ready version of entity framwork is version 6, and version 7 is being worked on.

I recommend you to move to Entity framework 6 which you can install into your Visual Studio project using Nuget: [EntityFramework 6.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework)

Here is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/21/productivity-improvements-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) which has a chapter about the differences the `DbSet` API brings compared to the old API. Take a look at the chapter "Introducing DbContext & DbSet".

Comment: I've given you the bounty because this answer was the most helpful so far. I managed to move my code to EF 6, though now instead of one set not working, none are working. Same Error. I wish that error message weren't so vague with so many possible causes!

Comment: Well, perhaps you can post a new question, this time with you new code using `DbSet` and pointing out that you are using EF 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CodeFirst you can always map the view as you map a table (with a DbSet) and then it should work.

Comment: The view is pulled into the .edmx using 'Update Model from Database' function, with no errors. I set the key on the correct property.  In the DbContext a dbSet<> is generated same as for all the other tables. 
To query the data I have a ObjectContext with a ObjectSet<> for each entity. This is where I am having trouble;  base.CreateObjectSet<CatalogItemSearch>("Stratus_X_TestEntities.CatalogItemSearch"); throws the exception